# Retrieve specific string from txt file in java

Tags: java, java-io

Hey I have a txt file I wanna read only a specific string from it.
 The File:

```
This Ticket Being Generated as You Confirm

Name    : John

Movie   : Batman

Location: MidVally

Time    : 7PM-9PM

Time    : 2

Seats   : [A-4, B-3, D-5, C-1, D-2, E-3]

UniqueID: Batman7PM-9PMMidVally
```

I only want to retrieve the UniqueID to save it in string to be in this case String UniqID = "Batman7PM-9PMMidVally". Any idea how to achieve it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Reading a string line by line should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public FileReader fr = new FileReader("path/to/your/file");
public BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String unique;
String line;
while((line =  br.readLine()) != null){
    if (line.contains("UniqueID"))
    {
        unique = line.split(":")[1].trim();
        break;
    }
}
```

if the file always has the same structure.

Comment: this haven't worked. The format will always be the same

Comment: Forgot to put it in a loop. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class TestClass {


    private static final String FILE_PATH = "YOUR-FILE-PATH";

    public static void main(String... a) {

        String uniqID = "";


        uniqID = getValueFromFile(FILE_PATH, "UniqueID");

        System.out.println("String UniqID = \"" + uniqID + "\"");

    }

    private static String getValueFromFile(String filePath, String id) {

        HashMap<String, String> map= readFile(filePath);
        String  value=searchMap(map,id);

        return value;


    }

    private static String searchMap(HashMap<String,String> map,String id) {


        try {

            if(map.containsKey(id))return map.get(id);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "Not Found";

    }

    private static HashMap readFile(String filePath) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {

            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                for (String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator) {
                    String[] lineValues = line.split(":");
                    if (lineValues.length == 2)
                        map.put(lineValues[0].trim(), lineValues[1].trim());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: **read file method** read the file line by line and split it to array

Comment: add the key **first value** as id in map and **second key** as value in the map
**second method -search map** search for a given key if found in map return it's value

Answer (score 0):

This is a json like structure except This Ticket Being Generated as You Confirm. Try to convert that text to json then try to retrieve the as key-value pair.